# Discrete Mathematics One-to-One Proof Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Is *α: A x B --> A* defined by *α(a,b) = a* one-to-one? (Assume A and B are ∅)

This is what I have so far.

Proof:

Let (x1,yn) is in A x B where n is a positive integer.
Suppose α(x1,y1) = x1 and α(x2,y2) = x2.
So (x1,y1) ≠ (x1,y2), but  α(x1,y1) = α (x1,y2).
Thus, this function is not one-to-one.

Comment: You mean **is not** one to one... right? One to one means that $x\neq y\implies f(x)\neq f(y)$. You have shown this doesn't hold, so $\alpha$ is **not** one to one.

Comment: Observe this holds as long as $B$ has more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are confusing *one-to-one* with **not** one-to-one. Then your proof that $\alpha$ is not one-to-one (another word is *injective*) is correct, as the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_1,y_2)$ are different but have the same first coordinate. However, this requires $y_1\ne y_2$, so $B$ must have at least two elements.

One note about the terminology: A function $f:X\to Y$ is called *one-to-one* because it sends only **one** element in $X$ to **one** element in $Y$. If there is an element $y$ in $Y$ with **two** elements $x,x'$ such that $f(x)=f(x')=y$, then it's not one-to-one. However, if for any $y\in Y$ there are either two elements or no element at all with $y$ as the image (so $\forall y\in Y:|f^{-1}(y)|\in\{2,0\}$), then $f$ is called *two-to-one*.

Comment: I forgot to type not one-to-one.